# Regex Tidyverse, how to capture expression if exists

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, regex-group

I am using regex to parse car names.
Since there are many `Golf` versions, I want to eliminate everything that comes after it, except in `Golf SportsWagen`.

My attempt is:

```
> some_versions <- c("Golf A5", "Golf SportsWagen", "Cross Golf", "Golf A6")
> str_replace( some_versions, "Golf( SportsWagen)?", "Golf\\1" )
[1] "Golf A5"   "Golf SportsWagen"   "Cross Golf"   "Golf A6"
```

But this gives the whole original vector `some_versions`

In contrast, if I run the matches I do get what's expected:

```
> str_match(some_versions, "Golf( SportsWagen)?")
     [,1]               [,2]          
[1,] "Golf"             NA            
[2,] "Golf SportsWagen" " SportsWagen"
[3,] "Golf"             NA            
[4,] "Golf"             NA
```

with `NA` where there's no match.

What I would want to get is:

```
> str_replace(some_versions, "pattern", "Golf\\1")
> "Golf"  "Golf SportsWagen"   "Golf"   "Golf"
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Also, my next requirement is to capture the `Cross Golf`.

Thanks.

Comment: What if there is no match? Try `str_replace( some_versions, ".*(Golf(?: SportsWagen)?).*", "\\1" )`

Comment: Or `sub(".*?Golf( SportsWagen)?.*", "Golf\\1", some_versions)`

Comment: Why not use `str_extract(some_versions, "Golf(?: SportsWagen)?")`? (Or, `"\\bGolf(?: SportsWagen\\b)?"` to match whole words)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This one helped me to this particular example, but I couldn't follow to my next requirement, which is to capture the `Cross Golf`.  
For this purpose, I could work out with @G5W that needed to consider the other characters.

Comment: `str_extract(some_versions, "(?:Cross )?Golf(?: SportsWagen)?")`?

Comment: Thanks.  That does work and gives me something to chew on.   Why doesn't it get captured in with `str_replace`?

Comment: `str_replace` *replaces* the text it matches. `str_extract` *pulls* substrings matched from the longer strings of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `str_extract` here rather than `str_replace`. `str_replace` *replaces* the text it matches. `str_extract` *pulls* substrings matched from the longer strings of text.

To solve the original task, you may use

```
str_extract(some_versions, "Golf(?: SportsWagen)?")
[1] "Golf"             "Golf SportsWagen" "Golf"             "Golf"
```

To also extract `Cross Golf` if there is `Cross` before `Golf`, use

```
str_extract(some_versions, "(?:Cross )?Golf(?: SportsWagen)?")
[1] "Golf"       "Golf"       "Cross Golf" "Golf"
```

So, `(?:Cross )?Golf(?: SportsWagen)?` matches an optional `Cross` and a space after it, then `Golf` is matched, and then an optional sequence of space + `SportsWagen` is matched.

Replace the spaces with `\\s+` to match any 1 or more whitespaces and wrap the words with `\\b`, word boundaries, if you need to match these strings as whole words.

For example:

```
str_extract(some_versions, "\\b(?:Cross\\s+)?Golf(?:\\s+SportsWagen)?\\b")
[1] "Golf"             "Golf SportsWagen" "Cross Golf"       "Golf"
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful.